# Cross Language Middlewares

Tags: network-programming, game-center, distributed, middleware, distributed-system

I am developing a gaming server for playing cards that needs a persistent connection between clients and this server.

so the server will accept connections from multiple clients, each of them has been developed with a different programming language.

I know that C# uses .Net remoting and java uses RMI, but I don't know if there is any middleware that can be used for various programming languages.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are plenty ...

There are two things you need to think about:

1. In which format do you want to transfer the data:

   - text (XML, JSON)
   - Binary (Protocol Buffers, ...)
2. How do you want to communicate with the server

   - HTTP (REST, WEB Services, ...)
   - Messaging (ZeroMQ, ...)
   - other protocols (RPC, RMI, ...)

Most of the communication works one way to the server and the server answers. This way for an interactive card game, you'd need to bug the server every few seconds if something has changed. Even though, it's the easiest way, it can introduce high latencies.

A way around this, would be:

- Streaming - you can open a stream as a response and feed updated data to the client
- bi-directional communication

Since bi-directional communication is almost never possible (because clients are in private networks behind firewalls) let's have a look at streaming.

We've implemented ~5-6 years ago streaming from C++ SAO-WebService to a .net client and it worked perfectly fine. http://www.webrtc.org/ is something new, for Real-Time-Communication (RTC) on the web. There are server endpoints implemented the most common languages / technologies and client endpoints shouldn't be limited to JavaScript only. But if you want to go more low-end, you can also always open a socket connection to the server and listen on incoming messages. However you loose the benefits of HTTP and other high level protocols.

I've explained parts of this in more detail, when answering the following question: [What is the use of REST in distributed web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539801/what-is-the-use-of-rest-in-distributed-web-application)